# COnfiguring Jager-agent to UDP server like FluentD using docker command

Tags: docker, fluentd, jaeger, opentracing

After going through different blogs/docs, we came to know that we can skip agent and send spans to jaeger collector from client.

But I am thinking of skipping collector and trying to send spans from jaeger agent to UDP server like fluentD.

Is it possible ? ANy pointers will be great help

Comment: Is it possible to skip collector and write ovr UDP server